# Does calling .body() from response Retrofit in try body might returns null?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have simple snippet code as below:

```
Sub sub = null;

try {
    Response<Sub> response = MyRestApi.getInstance().getSub().execute();
    sub = response.body(); // Does variable response is always non null?
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//
// ... further operations on sub
//
```

All that I want to know is, can I call safely `.body()` on `response`in `try` body?

I've tried to preview my method information `.getSub()` by calling `CTRL-Q` in Android Studio but I got the only line

```
Inferred annotations: @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
```

I believe it should be enough to convince me about that but I had to ask and be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be null, even when request is successful, as described on w3c:

> "Response data Additional information may follow, in the format of a
>   MIME message body. The significance of the data depends on the status
>   code.
>
> The Content-Type used for the data may be any Content-Type which the
>   client has expressed its ability to accept, or text/plain, or
>   text/html. That is, one can always assume that the client can handle
>   text/plain and text/html."

reference: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Response.html

In Retrofit, the body method is defined as Nullable

> @Nullable public T body() The deserialized response body of a
>   successful response.

https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be null, if the response not successful.